# Explain this vector sum

Tags: geometry

This image comes from a geometry problem I was doing and the solution said that $w = (v_1 −v_2 +u_2)−(u_1 +v_1) = u_2 −v_2 −u_1$. I don't understand how they are getting $w$ to equal that. These are vectors but I am omitting the vector sign. For clarification, $v_1 = CA, v_2 = BA, u_1 = CD, u_2 = BF$.

If it helps anyone, here was the original problem:

> Let triangle $ABC$ have side lengths $AB = 16, BC = 20, AC = 26$. Let $ACDE, ABFG,$ and
>   $BCHI$ be squares that are entirely outside of triangle $ABC$. Let $J$ be the midpoint of $EH, K$
>   be the midpoint of $DG$, and $L$ the midpoint of $AC$. Find the area of triangle $JKL$.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

$u_1+v_1=CE,$ so $-(u_1+v_1)=-CE=EC.$ This is the diagonal of the square starting at $E$ and ending at $C$.

$v_1-v_2+w_2=CF.$ And since $EC+CF=EF=w,$ you have what you want to show.

Note I was assuming $ACDE$ to be a square, in order to have $u_1+v_1=CE.$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
    -u_1 &= \overrightarrow{DC} = \overrightarrow{EA} \\
    -v_1 &= \overrightarrow{AC} \\
     v_1 &= \overrightarrow{CA} \\
    -v_2 &= \overrightarrow{AB} \\
     u_2 &= \overrightarrow{BF} \\
    \hline
    (v_1 −v_2 +u_2)−(u_1 +v_1) &= -u_1 - v_1 + v_1 -v_2 + u_2 \\
    &= \overrightarrow{EA} 
     + \overrightarrow{AC}
     + \overrightarrow{CA}
     + \overrightarrow{AB}
     + \overrightarrow{BF}\\
    &= \overrightarrow{EF} \\
    &= w
\end{align}